# Missing icons FontAwesome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

For a long time, some FontAwesome (last version) icons are not working on my project, like `fa-hashtag`, but there are couple of other icons that do not work as well. Already checked for some solution here in stack but nothing worked.

Here how is linked my fontawesome:

```
<link href="assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

An example of the code using bootstrap and the missing icon:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="uppercase bold">11. VALOR TOTAL DAS VENDAS DA LOJA (ÚLTIMO MÊS)</label>
        <div class="input-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-dollar font-green"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlrTotalVendas" placeholder="DIGITE AQUI O VALOR TOTAL DE VENDAS DA LOJA">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="uppercase bold">12. quantidade de tickets na Loja (último mês)</label>
        <div class="input-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-hashtag font-green"></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlrTicketMedio" placeholder="DIGITE AQUI A QUANTIDADE DE TICKETS DO ÚLTIMO MÊS">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain you have the latest version of font-awesome in your project?

Comment: Are you sure you checked all the other related questions. It's usually because the font files are not installed.

Comment: It's working for me [check fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6a3uw2p/)

Comment: @ZimSystem the fonts need to be installed in my computer? What about a user which does not even know about it?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey i see... dont't know why its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the following points can cause that problem

- File does not exist on the defined path 'assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
- The font-awesome.min.css file can be outdated (Thus the Dollar / Hash symbol will not exist)
- Somehow the file got corrupted or received a extra character within the code. (This will cause certain parts of the CSS not to work)

Solution: Try using the CDN and see if that works for you. (If yes save the file path on your local machine)

CDN: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: That's it! Using the CDN the hashtag worked pretty well, don't know why it stopped working with a local file, but i copied the code to my local `.min.css` file and now is working fine! Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

I tried with last version of font-awesome and fa-hashtag it's working. 
Try to change your link with

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```